# EF Code First collection as ComplexType

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

For performance reasons I am mapping a set of entities to a view creating a flat table (in a way transforming a TPT inheritance in a TPH). This is to be used only a specific method.

```
[view]
id
property1
property2
propertyN
complex_type_collection_property1
complex_type_collection_property2
complex_type_collection_propertyN
```

Is there a way to map the complex_type_collection_properties to a complex property on the materialized object?

e.g.

```
[Object]
id = [view].Id
property1 = [view].property1
property2 = [view].property2
propertyN = [view].propertyN
Collection = [{property1 = [view].complex_type_collection_property1, ...}, ...]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I created [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XP3CsJ), I assume that you already have entity(`fromDB` variable at my code, lets imagine that it taken from DB) or entities retrieved from DB. Than you can cast each entity as shown below. Solution is comprehensive and little sophisticated. You should also specify type parameter`Normalized<City>` that corresponds to your complex type (if you will want to change complex type to another one there will not needed to do any changes at casting method). Also names of your complex properties(*City1*, *City2*, etc) must contain name of collection property(*City*), it is - some conventions. And I created `BaseClass` with shared properties, our two classes derrived from it (so you able to not copy fields from one class to another, instead you should place them into `BaseClass`). Also you can have the only one collection, i.e. property of type `List<T>`.

```
public class City
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Population { get; set; }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class POCO : BaseClass
{
    public City City1 { get; set; }
    public City City2 { get; set; }
    public City City3 { get; set; }
}

public class Normalized<T> : BaseClass
{
    public List<T> City { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator Normalized<T>(POCO self)
    {
        if (self == null)
            return null;

        var normal = new Normalized<T>();

        foreach (var prop in typeof(BaseClass).GetProperties())
            prop.SetValue(normal, prop.GetValue(self));

        var complexProp = typeof(Normalized<T>).GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Any(y => y.Name == "ICollection")).First();
        complexProp.SetValue(normal, new List<T>((typeof(POCO).GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name.Contains(complexProp.Name)).Select(x => (T)x.GetValue(self)).ToList())));

        return normal;
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var fromDB = new POCO
    {
        Age = 20,
        id = 1,
        Name = "Mike",
        City1 = new City { Name = "Moscow", Population = 10 },
        City2 = new City { Name = "London", Population = 20 },
        City3 = null
    };
    var normal = (Normalized<City>)fromDB;
    Console.WriteLine(normal.City.Select(x => x == null ? "EMPTY" : x.Name).Aggregate((a, b) => { return a + ", " + b; }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How would you bring Entity Framework into play here? Would  you read all POCOs and then Normalize it in runtime?

Comment: Yes, I assume something like this: `var normalList = context.MyTable.Where(x => x.Age > 5).ToList().Select(x => (Normalized<City>)x).ToList();`

Comment: Also I simplified my answer, check out it.

Comment: Thanks Slava. Your answer assumes that each row has multiple cities, however, the command context.MyTable.Where(x => x.Age > 5) will return several rows with the same id and each would have a City. Is it even supported by EF? Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand you. Request: context.MyTable.Where(x => x.Age > 5) will return list of POCOs with unique ids(how duplicates will be appear?), furthermore all cities inside each POCO (City1, City2) also will have unique ids(it is depends on you, how you specified relationship between POCO and City tables). MyTable is a table of your model [view]. You just take list of [view](POCO) and then cast them with the help of class Normalized<T>. EF at this case **not mean anything** you can take your [view] from anywhere: EF, file, remote server, dataAdapter no metter.